# vb.net function to compare list of any object

Tags: vb.net, list, function, object, types

```
    Function keepOnlyDuplicates(ByRef list1 As List(Of Integer), ByRef list2 As List(Of Integer)) As List(Of Integer)
    Dim returnList As New List(Of Integer)
    For Each i As Integer In list1
        For Each j As Integer In list2
            If i = j Then
                returnList.Add(i)
                Exit For
            End If
        Next
    Next
    Return returnList
End Function
```

I made this function to make a new list of Integers from two others that only contains the integers that are in both (The individual lists have no duplicates).

Is there a way to modify this function so that it will accept a list of any type and return a list of according types without much trouble? If it's really complicated I could just as easily make another function for other types. But if it's just a matter of what type to call then how can I do it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Function keepOnlyDuplicates(Of t As IComparable)(ByRef list1 As List(Of t), ByRef list2 As List(Of t)) As List(Of t)
            Dim returnList As New List(Of t)
            For Each i As t In list1
                For Each j As t In list2

                    If i.CompareTo(j) = 0 Then
                        returnList.Add(i)
                        Exit For
                    End If
                Next
            Next
            Return returnList
        End Function
```

If t will be your own type then :

//for making fully comparable add your own type `Implements IComparable`

Or do this way . **if u will only check for equality**
change function to

```
 Function keepOnlyDuplicates(Of t)(ByRef list1 As List(Of t), ByRef list2 As List(Of t)) As List(Of t)
```

On this case for your own  types just override equal() .
change condition to

```
If i.Equals(True) = True Then .
```